# Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) Install of Unstable Fails

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to install unstable-desktop-full, by running

`sudo apt-get install ros-unstable-desktop-full`

on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-unstable-desktop-full: Depends: ros-unstable-vision-opencv (= 1.6.1-s1313731218~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ros-unstable-image-pipeline (= 1.5.2-s1313736766~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ros-unstable-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.1-s1313731295~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Any ideas why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12071/ubuntu-10.04-(lucid)-install-of-unstable-fails/) by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on 2011-11-25**:
Thanks, this fixed the problem I was having.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-23**:
@sdavies The tutorial was out of date.  I've updated it to use electric

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-11-23**:
Do you really need the bleeding edge unstable version? There is a perfectly fine electric release available as well... :-)

**Comment by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on 2011-11-23**:
For the same reasons, I am unable to run the following tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Installing%20TurtleBot%20Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While this may be an issue with OpenCV, just a heads up that the ROS team has stated that unstable will be *very* unstable during this early stage of development as low-level dependencies get a major overhaul for the upcoming Fuerte release. It is probably better to install the Electric release for most users.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on 2011-11-25**:
Ok, thanks.  After tfoote fixed the above tutorial, I no longer need to use unstable.